# Must Linear operators on entire Banach space $l^1$ be bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, unbounded-operators

Assume that it is possible to construct an unbounded linear functional $f$ defined on entire Banach space $l^1$. Then let us consider in unit ball the standard linearly independent sequence $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$, $e_i=(\underbrace{0,0,\ldots,0}_{n-1},1,0,\ldots)$. We choose $k$ such that for subsequence $\{e_{i_k}\}$, $f(e_{i_k})\geq k^2$.
Partial sums of the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty {k^{-2}}e_{i_k}$ form a Cauchy sequence in $l^1$, converging to $x_0\in l^1$ with coordinates $\frac1{k^2}$ in the $i_k$ places and zeros otherwise. Then $\forall\ n,\ f(x_0)\geq \sum_{k=1}^n k^{-2} f(e_{i_k})\geq \sum_{k=1}^n 
 1=n$. Thus, functional $f$ is undefined on $x_0\in l^1$.  Contradiction.
However, I found the claims that the axiom of choice allows to prove existence of unbounded functional defined on some Banach spaces.

Can I use this counterexample to conclude that space $l^1$ does not satisfy this property and there is no unbounded functionals defined on entire $l^1$?

Comment: On every infinite dimensional normed linear space there is an unbounded linear functional.

Comment: Where does $\ f(x_0)\geq \sum_{k=1}^n f(e_{i_k})\geq \sum_{k=1}^n 
 1=n$ come form? Are you assuming that $f(e_i) \geq 0$ for all $i$?

Comment: @Kavi Rama. I do _not_ assume $f(e_i)\geq0$ for all $i$. I consider SUBsequence, for which $f(e_{i_k})\geq k^2$. If operator $f$ is unbounded, then there is a SUBsequence such that either $f(e_{i_k})\geq k^2$ or $f(e_{i_k})\leq  -k^2$ (or both). Without loss of generality I consider the positive case only.

Comment: The actual problem is that you've given no proof that $f(x_0)\geq \sum_{k=1}^n k^{-2} f(e_{i_k})$. (You seem to think that's obvious - if so you should be able to prove it. Hint: It _would_ be obvious if $f$ were continuous; in fact it's easy to show that counterexamples exist.)

Comment: Some strange people here assigned negative points for my question. I  do not care too much but am just interested from the psychological viewpoint. Why they did that? Maybe they do not know that everyone asking a question on this site is trying to figure out the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course it's well known and not hard to show that the conclusion is false. Raising the question of where the error is. The following is at least one error that seems important:

You define $x_0$ to be a certain infinite sum; say the partial sums are $s_n$. You say that $f(s_n)$ has a certain property and then deduce something about $f(x_0)$. No! No, no, no. *Since* we don't know that $f$ is continuous, saying something about $f(s_n)$ says nothing about $f(x_0)$.

Hmm, the post does contain a correct proof that there cannot be a *continuous* unbounded functional, but of course we knew that...

**Edit:** The OP insists that he or she is *not* talking about convergence of infinite sums. But there's no justification given for the key inequality $f(x_0)\geq \sum_{k=1}^n k^{-2} f(e_{i_k})$, and in fact it need not hold.

### The Truth of the Matter

Oops, that word "truth" is a little tricky here. I'm going to assume the axiom of choice and then show that AC implies there exists a discontinuous linear functional $f$ on $\ell^1$, in particular one such that $f(x_0)< \sum_{k=1}^n k^{-2} f(e_{i_k})$.

Does that prove it's true? Maybe not; it's known that we can't prove AC (speaking loosely), so you're free to disbelieve in AC, hence in the validity of the argument. But **NOTE** it's also known that we can't *disprove* AC. So, while a proof that AC implies the existence of an unbounded functional may not show that an unbounded functional exists, it **does** show that any proof that every functional is bounded must be wrong! (Because that would prove AC was false, known to be impossible.)

So, as of now we as.assume AC.

> > **Exercise.** Suppose $x=(x_j)\in\ell^1$ and $x_j\ne0$ for infinitely many $j$. Suppose $\alpha, \alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots\in\Bbb R$. There exists a linear functional $f$ on $\ell^1$ such that $fx=\alpha$ and $fe_j=\alpha_j$.

Proof: The set $S=\{x\}\cup\{e_1,e_2,\dots\}$ is linearly independent (in the straight linear algebra *finite* linear combination sense), so this follows from elementary linear algebra (AC gives us a basis containing $S$, etc.)

> > **Elementary Linear Algebra** Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are vector spaces (over the same field), $S\subset X$ is independent, and $\phi:S\to Y$. There exists a linear map $f:X\to Y$ such that $f|_S=\phi$.

Comment: The only reason that I consider specific space $l^1$ instead of a general Banach space is to avoid the issue of the convergence of series, which you raise.  I consider $x_0$, which I treat _not_ as the a sum of the converging series, but as a _fixed_ element from $l^1$. More exactly, $x_0=(\underbrace{0,0,\ldots,0}_{i_1-1}, 1^{-2},\underbrace{0,0,\ldots,0}_{i_2-i_1},2^{-2},\underbrace{0,0,\ldots,0}_{i_3-i_2},3^{-2},\ldots)$. And the functional is not defined on this certain element from $l^1$.

Comment: Consequently, for arbitrary unbounded functional I can find point $x_0$ from $l^1$, such that the functional is _not_ defined at this point. This is a contradiction with the assumption that there exists an unbounded functional defined on _all_ Banach space.

Comment: You say the functional is not defined at $x_0$ but give no proof. In fact there exists a linear functional $f$  on $\ell_1$ such that $fe_j=j^3$ for every $j$ while $fx_0=-1$.

Comment: Thank you, David C, Ullrich, got it.

Answer (score 0):

As Kavi Rama Murthy says in the comments, there is nothing that ensures that $f(e_i)\ge0$ for all $i$. Also, your argument cannot possibly be correct because of the following reason:

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional Banach space and assume that every linear functional $X\to\mathbb{C}$ is bounded. Let $\{e_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a Hamel basis for $X$ consisting of vectors each of which has norm $1$. Since $\{e_i\}_{i\in I}$ is an infinite set, pick a countable subset, say $\{e_{i_k}\}_{k=1}^\infty$, so this is a linearly independent set.

Define $\phi:X\to\mathbb{C}$ by declaring $\phi(e_{i_k})=k^2$, $\phi(e_i)=0$ for $i\in I\setminus\{i_k:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and extend this linearly to the entire space $X$. By assumption, $\phi$ must be bounded, i.e. continuous. But, if $x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}e_{i_k}$ (the series converges in $X$ because $X$ is Banach and the series is absolutely convergent), then
$$\phi(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}\phi(e_{i_k})=\sum_{k=1}^\infty1=\infty$$
a contradiction.

One can come up with a slightly more involved argument for infinite dimensional normed spaces in general, without assuming completeness, I think you need the Hahn-Banach theorem for this.

Comment: You just confirmed my claim that the unbounded functional is _not_ defined at point $x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-2}e_{i_k}$. Consequently, it is _not_ defined on the _entire_ Banach space.

Comment: @pabodu No, I did not. I just confirmed that UNDER THE ASSUMPTION THAT every functional is bounded, we get a contradiction. so the assumption cannot be true.

Comment: You assumed that all functionals are bounded, picked up a specific functional and showed that your functional is _not_ defined at that point. You found a point where the functional if _not_ defined. The discussion is only about functionals defined _everywhere_ in Banach space. Therefore your example (actually, mine) does not serve as contradiction.

Comment: If we could prove, even without direct construction, that there exists an unbounded _everywhere_ defined functional, I'd be happy.

Comment: @pabodu I assumed all functionals are bounded, yes. I defined a specific functional that by definition is defined on the entire space. But, using the assumption that this functional is bounded (since I assumed all functionals are bounded), I showed that this functional is undefined at a specific point, which is a contradiction. Therefore the hypothesis that all functionals are bounded is wrong.

Comment: Thank you, JustDroppedin. Actually, the hypothesis is not 
"all functionals are bounded"
 but 
"all functionals _defined on the entire Banach space_ are bounded".
Youe input helped me understand and sharpen the issue better, thank you again.

Comment: @pabodu But these two are the same thing!!!! By definition a functional is defined on the entire space!!!!!!!!!